# Selenium: Message: invalid argument: invalid 'sameSite'

Tags: python, selenium

When I'm trying to import cookies from json to selenium, I got the error 
`selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid 'sameSite'`

Why is this problem happens and how should I fix it?
Edit: This is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver

cookies = [
{
    "domain": ".facebook.com",
    "hostOnly": False,
    "httpOnly": False,
    "name": "act",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "lax",
    "secure": True,
    "session": True,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "0000....000", #the value here is changed
    "id": 1
}
]

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
driver.add_cookie(cookies[0])
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
```

Comment: Code trials please....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is cause by the argument 'sameSite' in your cookie.

There are several rules on this parameter, and it's format and rules will update by new chrome version.
Basically, it's a value recording same-site / cross-site for some security reason - more details see the websites below:

1. [SameSite Cookie Attribute: What It Is And Why It Matters](https://adzerk.com/blog/chrome-samesite/)
2. [Chrome same-site update](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site)

After all, the simple way to solve this problem is to pop this 'sameSite'

Which be adding

```
cookies[0] = cookies[0].pop('sameSite')
```